# Finding the basis of a subspace in $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a basis of the subspace of ${\mathbb R}^4$ consisting of all vectors of the form
$$
\left\lbrack
\begin{array}{c}
x_1 \\
2 x_1 + x_2 \\
6 x_1 + 2 x_2 \\
8 x_1  - 4 x_2
\end{array}
\right\rbrack
$$
The answer should be a list of row vectors.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Can you, say, compute the dimension of the subspace?

Comment: I get that the dimension of the vector space is 2, and my initial answer is was two vectors <1,2,6,8> and <0,1,2,4>. However, my online homework says when I enter this in that it "Can't transpose 3-dimensional matrices"

Comment: Ah.  Well, I'd have said your answer was correct...but I suppose they want the vectors displayed in row form.  Sounds more like a formatting issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should post your attempts, so we know *where* in the process you're struggling.

Here's a worked out solution, please comment so we can help you learn instead of just giving you an answer.

Notice that $\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\2x_1+x_2\\6x_1+2x_2\\8x_1-4x_2 \end{bmatrix}$.

Recall that a basis is a set of vectors such that a linear combination of them can form every vector in the subspace.

We can rewrite the subspace as $x_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\6\\8 \end{bmatrix}+x_2\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\2\\-4 \end{bmatrix}$.

What does this reveal? This directly reveals the basis vectors, because by definition, any $x_1v_1+x_2v_2$ IS a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$.